# how to deal with 2 FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, error-handling, transactions

I have problem with my app which contains 2 fragment layout
when i want to change both fragment's at the same time from drawer item clicked
it give me error like that

```
2019-06-04 22:22:03.572 24088-24088/com.example.android.madbaloon3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.madbaloon3, PID: 24088
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:669)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at com.example.android.madbaloon3.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:195)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23752)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

first i set up fragments stuff in class

```
    private MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    private DataFragment dataFragment = new DataFragment();
    private InfoFragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
    private AboutFragment aboutFragment = new AboutFragment();
    private EmptyFragment emptyFragment = new EmptyFragment();


private FragmentTransaction transaction_top = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
private FragmentTransaction transaction_bottom = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

then in oncreate i set default fragment like that

```
transaction_bottom.replace(R.id.bottomFragment, dataFragment);
        transaction_bottom.commit();
        bottom_fragment_name="dataFragment";


        transaction_top.replace(R.id.topFragment, mapFragment);
        transaction_top.commit();
        top_fragment_name="mapFragment";
```

and then i whant to change both fragments while someone click on drawer item

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_map:

                transaction_top.replace(R.id.topFragment, mapFragment);
                transaction_top.commit();

                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:


                transaction_top.replace(R.id.topFragment,aboutFragment);
                transaction_top.commit();


                transaction_top.replace(R.id.bottomFragment,infoFragment);
                transaction_bottom.commit();


            default:
                break;

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

fragment loyout ( i mean content_main.xml )

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/topFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_info"
            />
```

I've been try to remove fragment in transaction before replace it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error states:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

That means, you're trying to commit the FragmentTransaction twice somewhere in your activity.

You'll be able to see, in your `onNavigationItemSelected`, in `case R.id.nav_about`, you've written this code.

```
transaction_top.replace(R.id.bottomFragment,infoFragment);
transaction_bottom.commit();
```

In that case, you've already committed the transaction_bottom before, but here you're trying to do it again without making any changes to the transaction. So you'll have to change it to,

```
transaction_bottom.replace(R.id.bottomFragment,infoFragment);
transaction_bottom.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The **java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called** is being thrown because you have committed the **transaction_top** and are trying to change another fragment via the same transaction. Perhaps what you intended to write was

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction_top = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FragmentTransaction transaction_bottom = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_map:

            transaction_top.replace(R.id.topFragment, mapFragment);
            transaction_top.commit();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:


            transaction_top.replace(R.id.topFragment,aboutFragment);
            transaction_top.commit();


            transaction_bottom.replace(R.id.bottomFragment,infoFragment);
            transaction_bottom.commit();


        default:
            break;

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Note that you have to start new FragmentTransactions every time the **onNavigationSelected** function is called because you wish to change fragments.

On a further note, you do not need to create two separate FragmentTransaction objects **transaction_top** and **transaction_bottom**, you can instead create a single FragmentTransaction object and change both the fragments within the same transaction as follows

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_map:

            transaction.replace(R.id.topFragment, mapFragment);
            transaction.commit();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:


            transaction.replace(R.id.topFragment,aboutFragment);
            transaction.replace(R.id.bottomFragment,infoFragment);
            transaction.commit();


        default:
            break;

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```